# Pop to root view using Tab Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any way to pop to root view by tapping the Tab Bar like most iOS apps, in SwiftUI?

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBEvL.gif) of the expected behavior.

[image]

I've tried to programmatically pop views using `simultaneousGesture` as follow:

```
import SwiftUI


struct TabbedView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            RootView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                        .simultaneousGesture(
                            TapGesture().onEnded {
                                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                                print("View popped")
                            }
                        )
                }.tag(0)
                
            Text("")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tapping the house icon should pop back to root view")
    }
}
```

But seems like those gestures were ignored.

Any suggestions or solutions are greatly appreciated

Comment: No answer yet? T_T

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Nik No I didn't. I don't think this is possible with the current SwiftUI :(

Comment: Am I understanding right, that this default iOS functionality doesn't work from the box on SwiftUI 1.0/2.0/3.0?

Comment: @surfrider Your understanding is correct. SwiftUI 1.0/2.0/3.0 by default doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Ok thank you Nguyễn Khắc Hào. That's dissapointing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my own app I use the approach of changing the .id modifier on the topmost view which causes the NavigationView to pop to root.  For clarity I also factored out this nav-popping behavior into its own wrapper view, "TabbedNavView", as shown below.

```
import SwiftUI

class TabMonitor: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = 1
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var tabMonitor = TabMonitor()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabMonitor.selectedTab) {
            TabbedNavView(tag: 1) {
                DetailView(index: 1)
            }
            .tabItem { Label("Tab1", systemImage: "book") }
            .tag(1)
            
            TabbedNavView(tag: 2) {
                DetailView(index: 10)
            }
            .tabItem { Label("Tab2", systemImage: "wrench") }
            .tag(2)
        } //TabView
        .environmentObject(tabMonitor)
    } //body
} //ContentView


struct DetailView: View {
    var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: DetailView(index: index + 1)
        ) {
            Text("Detail \(index)")
        }
    } //body
} //DetailView

struct TabbedNavView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tabMonitor: TabMonitor
    
    private var tag: Int
    private var content: AnyView

    init(
        tag: Int,
        @ViewBuilder _ content: () -> any View
    ) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.content = AnyView(content())
    } //init(tag:content:)

    @State private var id = 1
    @State private var selected = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content
                .id(id)
                .onReceive(tabMonitor.$selectedTab) { selection in
                    if selection != tag {
                        selected = false
                    } else {
                        if selected {
                            id *= -1 //id change causes pop to root
                        }

                        selected = true
                    }
                } //.onReceive
        } //NavigationView
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    } //body
} //TabbedNavView
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it works with any number of tabs, and any number of NavigationLinks within each tab.  Each TabbedNavView keeps track of whether itself is the selected tab, and pops the NavigationView to root (by flipping the sign of the root view's .id modifier) whenever a tab is tapped twice in a row.

Edit: works with iOS 15+.

Comment: I used an approach like this for my app too. I think this also works for iOS 14. Basically, we force the topmost view to refresh to pop to root. I've found this workaround to be the simplest solution, even for SwiftUI 4.0 / iOS 16.

Answer (score 9):

We can use tab bar selection binding to get the selected index. On this binding we can check if the tab is already selected then pop to root for navigation on selection.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var showingDetail = false
@State var selectedIndex:Int = 0

var selectionBinding: Binding<Int> { Binding(
    get: {
        self.selectedIndex
    },
    set: {
        if $0 == self.selectedIndex && $0 == 0 && showingDetail {
            print("Pop to root view for first tab!!")
            showingDetail = false
        }
        self.selectedIndex = $0
    }
)}

var body: some View {
    
    TabView(selection:selectionBinding) {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("First View")
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), isActive: $showingDetail) {
                    Text("Go to detail")
                }
            }
        }
        .tabItem { Text("First") }.tag(0)
        
        Text("Second View")
            .tabItem { Text("Second") }.tag(1)
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
 var body: some View {
    Text("Detail")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've waited 2 years for this! You'll have to create a unique ``isActive`` boolean for each ``NavigationLink``, which can be quite annoying sometimes though.

Comment: You don't have to put isActive for each NavigationLink, this only isActive flag will help you to navigate to root.

Comment: But I added a second NavigationLink that navigates to a new view (`Detail 2`), and the two NavigationLink randomly navigates to `Detail` or `Detail 2` when using the same isActive. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/qBWwVXF)

Comment: Oh, I understand it, that could make a little mess. But I think it could be a 
suitable solution until the default support for this feature.

Comment: still can't see solution "how pop to root" in your answer :(

Comment: @zslavman use observe notification

Answer (score 5):

I messed around with this for a while and this works great. I combined answers from all over and added some stuff of my own. I'm a beginner at Swift so feel free to make improvements.

Here's a demo.

[image]

This view has the NavigationView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AuthenticatedView: View {
    
    @StateObject var tabState = TabState()
            
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabState.selectedTab) {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView(titleNum: 0), isActive: $tabState.showTabRoots[0]) {
                    Text("GOTO TestView #1")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(height:50)
                        .background(Color.purple)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                .navigationTitle("")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                tabState.lastSelectedTab = TabState.Tab.first
            }).tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "list.dash")
            }.tag(TabState.Tab.first)
            
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: TestView(titleNum: 0), isActive: $tabState.showTabRoots[1]) {
                    Text("GOTO TestView #2")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(height:50)
                        .background(Color.purple)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }.navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline).navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                tabState.lastSelectedTab = TabState.Tab.second
            }).tabItem {
                Label("Second", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
            }.tag(TabState.Tab.second)
        }
        .onReceive(tabState.$selectedTab) { selection in
            if selection == tabState.lastSelectedTab {
                tabState.showTabRoots[selection.rawValue] = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AuthenticatedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AuthenticatedView()
    }
}

class TabState: ObservableObject {
    enum Tab: Int, CaseIterable {
        case first = 0
        case second = 1
    }
        
    @Published var selectedTab: Tab = .first
    @Published var lastSelectedTab: Tab = .first
    
    @Published var showTabRoots = Tab.allCases.map { _ in
        false
    }
}
```

This is my child view

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    let titleNum: Int
    let title: String
    
    init(titleNum: Int) {
        self.titleNum = titleNum
        self.title = "TestView #\(titleNum)"
    }
       
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView(titleNum: titleNum + 1)) {
                Text("Goto View #\(titleNum + 1)")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(height:50)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView(titleNum: titleNum + 100)) {
                Text("Goto View #\(titleNum + 100)")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .frame(height:50)
                    .background(Color.purple)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .navigationTitle(title)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(titleNum: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. In addition you could also add `TabState` as an environment object to allow each tab to be a separate view (and avoid massive view hierarchy in the TabView itself).

Comment: @Philio I'll have to look in to that because I noticed while I was messing with this example, my memory usage would just continue growing as I would navigate. It was like I had a memory leak somewhere. I think your suggestion is the missing piece to the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: @Bropane do you have usable example using it as environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple solution that works for me.

I use a a state variable `goHome` and assign a `UUID()` to it.
Using `onTapGesture` with a count of 2 assigns a new `UUID()` to `goHome` which resets the `TabView` to its initial state.

Double tapping anywhere on any screen in the 'stack' resets tabview and takes you back to the tabview 'root'.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection: Int = 1
    @State private var goHome = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
            DocumentsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext.fill")
                    Text("Documents")
                }.tag(3)
            ToolsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "wrench.and.screwdriver.fill")
                    Text("Tools")
                }.tag(4)
        }
        .id(goHome)
        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
            goHome = UUID()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is lacking the pop animation unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would add animation to [@StarRayder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15225976/starrayder) solution. It will simulate the default-like NavigationView's animation.

1. Add this anywhere to the project:

```
    extension AnyTransition {
        static var customTransition: AnyTransition {
            let insertion = AnyTransition.move(edge: .leading)
            let removal = AnyTransition.move(edge: .trailing)
            return .asymmetric(insertion: insertion, removal: removal)
        }
    }
```

2. After .id(goHome) add this line:

```
    .transition(.customTransition)
```

Comment: Please [edit] and spell @StarRayder 's username correctly ;-)

Comment: Mmmm... Is this working for anyone, does not work for me for some reason?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by having the TabView within a NavigationView like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                FirstTabView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                    }
                    .tag(0)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct FirstTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("SecondView Link", destination: SecondView())
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't having the TabView within the NavigationView causes the tab bar to move away when the first view moves away? [Example](https://imgur.com/I7Rnv6U)

Comment: I would strongly recommend against ever putting a TabView inside a NavigationView (at least at the moment), since it will cause all kinds of terrible bugs that you won't be able to fix unless you put the TabView outside of the NavigationView