# How to reset to default version of a View when TabView is pressed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to implement a feature where a view "reverts to default" if its corresponding tab item in the tab bar is tapped while the view is currently active. How can I achieve this?
My TabBar is implemented like this:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                HomeView()
                    .tag(TabBarItem.Home)
                UserAnalyticsView()
                    .tag(TabBarItem.Analytics)
                UserProfileView()
                    .tag(TabBarItem.Profile)
            }
            Divider()
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(TabBarItem.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                    TabBarButton(item: item, currentTab: $currentTab)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
```

For example, if a user is inside a NavigationLink on the homepage, and they were to click the home button on the tabview, it would revert out of the NavigationLink and back to the top of the homepage

Comment: Are you asking how to reset your view, or how to detect the second tap on the already selected tab?

Comment: @ChrisR the resetting view part, I think I can detect the second tap

Comment: Then you should look into `NavigationLink(isActive: )` and/or `NavigationLink(tag: selection: )`. These let you programmatically control navigation links. But it might become tricky if your nav hierarchy is deep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576918/swiftui-how-to-switch-to-a-new-navigation-stack-with-navigationviews  or  even more you case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109986/pop-to-root-view-using-tab-bar-in-swiftui